# FabricJS 2 – serializing canvas to JSON

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am serializing my canvas to JSON and facing 2 problems:

The width and height of my canvas will not be serialized but I would need that.

While a plain color and an image as canvas background will be serialized, a gradient as background will not be serialized. I am creating my background-gradient like this:

```
$scope.addGradient = function (left, right) {
    var leftColor = document.getElementById('gradLeft').value;
    var rightColor = document.getElementById('gradRight').value;
    console.log(leftColor, rightColor);

    var grad = new fabric.Gradient({
        type: 'linear',
        coords: {
            x1: 0,
            y1: 0,
            x2: canvas.width,
            y2: canvas.height,
        },
        colorStops: [{
            color: leftColor,
            offset: 0,
        },
            {
                color: rightColor,
                offset: 1,
            }
        ]
    });
    canvas.backgroundColor = grad.toLive(canvas.contextContainer);
    canvas.renderAll();
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate json like this.

```
GenerateCanvasJson(){
  return{
    leftColor: document.getElementById('gradLeft').value,
    rightColor: document.getElementById('gradRight').value,
    canvasWidth: canvas.original.width,
    canvasHeight: canvas.original.height,
    state: canvas.toJSON()
  }
}
```

If you want to save object's `name` and `size`
you can do like this.

```
GenerateCanvasJson(){
  return{
    leftColor: document.getElementById('gradLeft').value,
    rightColor: document.getElementById('gradRight').value,
    canvasWidth: canvas.original.width,
    canvasHeight: canvas.original.height,
    state: canvas.toJSON('name', 'size')
  }
}
```

Comment: We are using now something like this: 'fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(canvas),' – will your first function also strigify all the objects that are on the canvas with all properties to the same JSON structure? Or would the function require to specify explicitely what props i would like to stringify? Thanks!

Comment: In fact I would like to output all the defined and all the default values of the objects plus the dimensions and the colors of the canvas...

Comment: You can save like this `fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(GenerateCanvasJson())`

Comment: thsi is very cool – just the questions remains if I have to specify the objects atrributes to be outputted or does this happening automatically?

Comment: for default, `toJSON` save attribute `type`, `originX`,`originY`, `left`, `top`, `width`,`height`,`fill`, `stroke`, `strokeWidth`, ... and if you want add more attribute(custom attribute) like 'name' you have to use second way.

Comment: so, something like `canvas.includeDefaultValues = true;` would be making sense there... ?

Comment: I cant understand what you are thinking, anyway try to save file as mentioned and see that.

Comment: yes, sure I will implement this this afternoon when I am in the office :-) Will give you response anyhow. But just to try to explain: I have some object attributes that are defined when I am creating my objects  (like size, fill, etc.) some other attributes are not defined at object creation, but far as I know all "default" attributes that an object can have, can be exported to JSON (according to my reads). This is what I suppose that "includeDefaultValues" would be doing... Hope this makes sense...